# Nullhomotopic loops in $R^3$ minus two disjoint circles.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose we have two disjoint circles in $\mathbb{R}^3$: $C_1=\{(x,y,1)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $C_2=\{(x,y,2)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2=1\}$. Define $X=\mathbb{R}^3-C_1$, $Y=\mathbb{R}^3-C_2$, $Z=\mathbb{R}^3-C_1-C_2$.

I am trying to find a loop that is not nullhomotopic in $Z$, but is nullhomotopic in $X$ and $Y$. I have no idea how to do that... Any hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpret this problem by way of another: how can you hang a painting with two pins and a string so that if either pin is removed the painting falls? This might seem completely out of left field but there is a direct analogy here. For one, replace these pins with rubber bands (perhaps being held up on the wall by tape), so that wrapping the string around the pin is replaced by inserting it into the loop of the rubber band. These rubber bands will serve as our two disjoint circles. Furthermore, the painting will contain a path connecting the two endpoints of the string, and it can just deformation retract onto this, so the painting and the string serve as the loop.

Let's consider first the initial configuration of the painting hanging. It's not falling because somehow the string is looped into the rubber bands in such a way that it cannot be removed without cutting. The string cannot cut through the rubber band itself, in the same way that a loop going through the center of a circle is not null homotopic. The only way for the painting to fall is for the string to be able to unhook from the inside of the rubber bands, thus allowing the string and painting to be completely separate from the rubber bands. This is essentially saying that the corresponding loop is null homotopic!

Furthermore, going from $Z$ to $X$ or $Y$ is analogous to removing one of the rubber bands from the system. Adding in $C_1$ or $C_2$ allows our loop to pass through that area freely, just as removing a rubber band allows our string to fall through the area where it used to be.

I hope this convinces you that this problem is the same as the painting one I'm describing. For me, I find this much easier to visualize and understand. For one, you can pretty easily get some string and pins and go for it! Unfortunately, I don't think I have the ability to paint a mental picture of such a construction, nor can I draw one. So I'll leave you with [this fun little video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eVd2Ugk9BU) which shows a solution to this painting hanging problem and does a good job of motivating how you can arrive at such a solution.